# Solution to a Homogeneous Difference Equation

Tags: recurrence-relations, solution-verification

I am trying to find the solution to the difference equation $$a_{n+1}=3a_n \ \ \text{with} \ \ a_0=1. $$
As a trial solution, I substitute $a_n=C\lambda^n$ into the difference equation. This gives $\lambda=3$, and so $a_n=C3^n$. Applying $a_0=1$ gives $C=1$, and so the solution is $$a_n=3^n.$$
Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

Computed by hand,

$$a_0=1,a_1=3,a_2=3^2,a_3=3^3,\cdots$$ leaves little doubt.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1=3a_0,~ a_2=3 a_1,~ a_3= 3 a_2,...,a_{n-1}=3a_{n-2},~ a_n=3 a_{n-1}$$
Multipy all these equations, left and right cancellations will take place
and you get $$a_n=a_0 3^n, a_0=1 \implies a_n =3^n$$

Comment: Thanks I corrected this t and one more.